# How to disable associations tracking for a certain model using paper_trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I want to disable the associations or some of the associations tracking for a certain model. I am currently using 4.0.0.rc2 & MySQL but can upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
has_paper_trail(ignore: [:association1, association2])
```

Or the opposite, if you only want certain attributes:

```
has_paper_trail(only: [:something])
```

**UPDATE**

Link to documentation: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#2c-choosing-attributes-to-monitor

Comment: Is this correct, re: `ignore`? I don't see code or tests to support this usage, but it's late and I'm sleepy...

Comment: But associations are not treated the same as other attributes. See the `save_associations` method, which does not respect the `ignore` option, AFAICT.